# How to hide an entire DIV in a rails project if no data is being passed to it from the CMS?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb, refinerycms

Using Refinery CMS to create product pages in our prototype. An admin can add a link to the main product page, and it will display similar to

**Product Links**
www.example.com/product/1
www.example.com/product/2

here is a screenshot of how it currently is being displayed

[image: when product link is added]

However, there will not always be a case when the ink is added. And this looks weird to have that field but no links in there because every element has `margin-bottom:30px;`

[image: When no link is added]

So my question is how do I make the element not show up at all if nothing is passed to it. Here is the code for the element:

**HTML**

```
<div class="contentPageElement">
  <h3>Product Links</h3>
  <%= link_to @discussion.link.to_s, @discussion.link %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either put it in helper,or do something like this.

```
<% unless @discussion.link.empty? %>
<div class="contentPageElement">
  <h3>Product Links</h3>
  <%= link_to @discussion.link.to_s, @discussion.link %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_unless